# Origin of 'r' in 'rencontrar'

Tags: etimología

The Spanish equivalent of the English word "encounter" is "rencontrar."  Why does the Spanish version have the beginning "r" when the English one doesn't?

The source is the Spanish version of "Tea for Two,"

> Tu serás aquel amor, que yo soñé en rencontrar.

I learned the song years ago, but can't find a google version.

Comment: This sounds like two questions; one of which is on-topic on this site.  That being "What is the etymology of *rencontrar*?"  For the other ("What is the etymology of *encounter*?), [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Flimzy: The intent of the question is, "why is the Spanish form different from the English one" (specifically, where does the "r" come from). I may have asked the same question two ways, and it may also have lost something in the editing.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a very interesting question, but please see my related [meta post](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/182/12), and offer your feedback there.  I don't want to make a unilateral decision.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, the Spanish equivalent of *encounter* is *encuentro* o *encontrar*, not *rencontrar*. The song you are referring to might be saying *reencontrar*, which is the word *encuentro* with the prefix *re*. That prefix means repetition or augmentation, depending on context. You can find it with a hyphen (`-`), like *re-encontrar*, or without it: *reencontrar*.

In the song you are quoting it is like saying encounter or find it again as in once I had it and I lost it: *alguna vez soñé con reencontrarlo.*

Comment: As a side note, it's worth noting that *rencontrar* is a valid spelling, although *reencontrar* is preferred: "Tanto en el verbo como en el sustantivo de acción correspondiente, *reencuentro*, son admisibles las grafías reducidas *rencontrar(se)* y *rencuentro*. Se recomiendan, sin embargo, las grafías con *-ee-*, que son las preferidas en el uso." ([DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=reencontrar))

Answer (score 11):

The premise that the Spanish equivalent of "encounter" is "rencontrar" is false.

"Rencontrar" means "to re-encounter", or to encounter again, for a second time for example. Hence the "r".

Comment: That's a good thing to know. You corrected a mistake on my part. an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The etymology comes from the Latin prefix "re", see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/re-#Prefix_9).

The word in Spanish is also "reencontrar", which is clearer on the origin, (rencontrar is an evolution coming from the use).